# Stack overflow exception

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.Treeview` control with check boxes to build a permission tree, the nodes are dynamically built from DB Records along with custom nodes added from code behind `Allow Add`, `Allow Delete`, `Allow Update`.

The problem is when I try to retrieve the check nodes from the tree I get a `StackOverflowException`.

Here is my code:

```
List<tbl_JobPermission> SaveCheckedPermissions(int _JobID, System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection theNodes)
{
    using (WFMDBEntities _DBContext = new WFMDBEntities())
    {
        tbl_JobPermission _JopPermissionHelperVar;
        if (theNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode aNode in theNodes.OfType<System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode>().Where(x => x.Checked == true))
            {
                int _tempJobPermID = int.Parse(aNode.Parent.Name);
                if (aNode.Name.Contains('_'))
                {
                    _JopPermissionHelperVar =
                            new tbl_JobPermission()
                            {
                                TblPremition = _tempJobPermID,
                                Tbljob = _JobID
                            };
                    if (aNode.Name.ToLower().Contains("add"))
                    {
                        _JopPermissionHelperVar.AllowNew = true;
                    }
                    else if (aNode.Name.ToLower().Contains("update"))
                    {
                        _JopPermissionHelperVar.AllowUpdate = true;
                    }
                    else if (aNode.Name.ToLower().Contains("delete"))
                    {
                        _JopPermissionHelperVar.AllowDelete = true;
                    }

                    if (!_JobPermissions.Contains(_JopPermissionHelperVar))
                    {
                        _JobPermissions.Add(_JopPermissionHelperVar);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _JopPermissionHelperVar =
                            new tbl_JobPermission()
                            {
                                TblPremition = int.Parse(aNode.Name),
                                Tbljob = _JobID
                            };
                    if (!_JobPermissions.Contains(_JopPermissionHelperVar))
                    {
                        _JobPermissions.Add(_JopPermissionHelperVar);
                    }
                }
                if (aNode.Nodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    _JobPermissions.AddRange(SaveCheckedPermissions(_JobID, aNode.Nodes));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return _JobPermissions;
}
```

Comment: Any chance for same node appearing more than once in the tree? Does each node have some unique identifier?

Comment: see if you are doing it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wwc698z7.aspx

Comment: @ShadowWizard each and every Node has a unique name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why I got the StackOverFlow exception, the problem was not in calling the method recursively it was in the return, I was returning a List of the data acquired each time I call the method, so the List items reached a point where they doubles drastically, so what I did was simple ==> I made the method return  type Void not a list [ Because I will be filling that List(which is declared in class scope)

```
void SaveCheckedPermissions(int _JobID, System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode RootNode)
{
    using (WFMDBEntities _DBContext = new WFMDBEntities())
    {
        tbl_JobPermission _JopPermissionHelperVar;

        foreach (System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode aNode in RootNode.Nodes)
        {
            if (aNode.Checked == true)
            {
                int _tempJobPermID;
                int.TryParse(aNode.Name, out _tempJobPermID);
                _JopPermissionHelperVar = new tbl_JobPermission();
                _JopPermissionHelperVar.Tbljob = _JobID;
                if (aNode.Name.Contains('_'))
                {
                    int _tempSpecialJobPermID;
                    int.TryParse(aNode.Parent.Name, out _tempSpecialJobPermID);
                    if (_JobPermissions.Where(x => x.TblPremition == _tempSpecialJobPermID).FirstOrDefault() != null)
                    {
                        _JobPermissions.Where(x => x.TblPremition == _tempSpecialJobPermID).FirstOrDefault().TblPremition = _tempSpecialJobPermID;
                        if (aNode.Name.ToLower().Contains("add"))
                        {
                            _JobPermissions.Where(x => x.TblPremition == _tempSpecialJobPermID).FirstOrDefault().AllowNew = true;
                        }
                        else if (aNode.Name.ToLower().Contains("update"))
                        {
                            _JobPermissions.Where(x => x.TblPremition == _tempSpecialJobPermID).FirstOrDefault().AllowUpdate = true;
                        }
                        else if (aNode.Name.ToLower().Contains("delete"))
                        {
                            _JobPermissions.Where(x => x.TblPremition == _tempSpecialJobPermID).FirstOrDefault().AllowDelete = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (_JobPermissions.Where(x => x.TblPremition == _tempJobPermID).FirstOrDefault() == null)
                    {
                        _JopPermissionHelperVar.TblPremition = _tempJobPermID;
                    }

                }

                if (_JobPermissions.Where(x => x.TblPremition == _JopPermissionHelperVar.TblPremition && x.Tbljob == _JopPermissionHelperVar.Tbljob).ToList().Count < 1)
                {
                    _JobPermissions.Add(_JopPermissionHelperVar);
                }
            }
            SaveCheckedPermissions(_JobID, aNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a recursive call here:

```
if (aNode.Nodes.Count > 0)
{
    _JobPermissions.AddRange(SaveCheckedPermissions(_JobID, aNode.Nodes));
}
```

Check that you have reduced the number of nodes before recursing by running under the debugger.

I think that if *all* the nodes are checked at a particular level, it will recurse infinitely.

[EDIT]

It could just be that the node levels are too many. How many levels of recursion does it get to before crashing? Can you instrument it with Debug.WriteLines?

Comment: Well I Use the recursive call to Traverse through the children of the current Node, otherwise I will only get the root nodes, and also I check for the count if (aNode.Nodes.Count > 0) here to know if the current node has children of not

Comment: The code is fairly complex, so I think the only way to discover what's going on is to single step it in the debugger.

Comment: I think I solved the recursion issue, I will post the solution soon enough :)